# How to add seller in JA MarketPlace prestashop plugin to multiple products (SOLVED)

Tags: plugins, prestashop, marketplace

I solved it going into the prestashop database, searching for "ps_seller_product" table and adding with a query all the products.

**table explained;**

id_seller_product   id_seller              id_product
x (auto_incremental)     seller_id(in "sellers)     the product id

**query example;**

INSERT INTO ps_seller_product (id_seller, id_product)
VALUES
(7,6608),
(7,6609),
(7,6610),
(7,6611);

123456789101112131415